# How to Identify Necessary Debian Packages for an Application in Docker for Minimalistic Setup

Tags: linux, docker, package, debian, strace

I'm working with Docker and have a container running an application named "App". My goal is to create a more minimalistic Docker container that includes only the essential Debian packages required for "App" to function.

Current Approach:
I tried running "App" with strace in the main Docker container, hoping to identify the necessary packages. However, I'm struggling to determine the specific packages from the strace output.

Question:
Is there a way to accurately identify which Debian packages are required to run "App"? Any method or tool that can analyze my main Docker container and list the necessary packages would be greatly helpful.